# Registered server ram on z9pe-d8 ws server motherboard 5 sticks vs 6 sticks

Tags: memory

I only require 80gb of memory for my server what would fill 5 slots out of the 6 on my z9pe-d8 ws motherboard and was wondering if I would have performance issue due to not filling the last slot ?

Answer (score 0):

No, there should not be any performance issue.

For the last stick you can't use the dual-cannel option which *could* increase performance a little bit, but as you are already using dual-channel for the other four sticks you should not have any performance issues, at least where RAM is concerned.

Comment: So 4 sticks would run it dual channel and the 5th stick would run a bit slower on single channel ?

Comment: Yes, altough the 5. bank would not be slower. The server just culdn't utlilize the advantages of dual-channel.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses so far been really helpful :) last question does the motherboard having 2x e5 2690 make a difference knowing they will be 3 stick for 1 cpu and 2 sticks for other. I also was a mistake it 5 slots out of the 8 slots available I will be using.

Comment: It's the same as above you use (2+1) + 2. You have to be careful to place them in the correct slots as described in the [Manual section 2.4.1](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2011/Z9PE-D8-WS/Manual/E12544_Z9PE-D8_WS_UM_V5_WEB.pdf#p36) e.g. A and C each two DIMMs and B *or* D only one DIMM

Comment: The manual says cpu configuration (must on cpu 1) 1 dimms 2 dimms 3 dimms cpu configuration cpu 2 1 dimms 2 dimms 4 dimms 8 dimms. Not seeing anything for 5 dimms setup.

Comment: I'll correct my answer, one moment please.

Comment: I have also found a 8gb stick of ram that has the same speed and CL11 but it has a higher voltage at 1.5v when the other ram will be 1.35v any chance I could throw that in to make up the 6th slot ?

Comment: You are of course correct, you can't have five DIMMs on this Motherboard. As it looks like, you can't have six DIMMs either. You must have 2 or 4 or 8 RAM Sticks. 6 are not possible.

Comment: I have 8 slots (A) E1, F1 (B) H1, G1 (C) A1, B1 (D) D1, C1 so i would put 2 sticks IN C what would be A1, B1 then another 2 sticks in A what would be E1, F1 then the last stick can go into any ofnthe 4 slots in B or D ?

Comment: So I am forced to either go 4 or 8 sticks well that sucks

Comment: Seems like it, you can try if it works or ask the ASUS Support but no guarantee what will happen.

Comment: So I took out 3 sticks of my corsair vengeance 8gb ram so they is now 5 sticks and it running so should the 5 sticks of registered server ram work also ?

Comment: you can always try, but ASUS may not support you if there is a hardware issue as a result.

Comment: Should I not be ok if they is no fault now or are you saying fault can develop at A later date?

Comment: Also could I go 4 sticks 16gb and 4 sticks 8gb ?

Comment: 4x 16GB + 4x 8GB is ok. fault should develop instantly but if there are issues caused by memory lare on you may not get support because you did not follow their instructions